# Scala - type inference of generic parameter with traits

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference, traits

I'm working on an small rendering engine in Scala to learn the language. The architecture of the engine is strongly based on traits, so I can add and remove parts of the pipeline as I want. Some of the traits are:

(**update**: Corrected some type information)

```
trait Composable { val parent:DisplayObject with Composite = null }
trait Composite extends Composable { val children:ArrayBuffer[DisplayObject with Composable] = ArrayBuffer() }
trait Position { var x = 0.0d; var y = 0.0d }
...
```

`DisplayObject` is an empty class that is used to compose those traits.

One of the step in my pipeline is flattening a hierarchy of each object. My first shot at this was was: 
(**update**: I added the body)

```
def flatten(root:DisplayObject with Composite) : ArrayBuffer[DisplayObject] =
{
    def traverse(composite:Composite, acc:ArrayBuffer[DisplayObject])
    {
      acc += composite
      for(composable <- composite.children)
      {
        composable match {
          case com:Composite => traverse(com, acc)
          case _ => acc += composable
        }
      }
    }

    val flat = new ArrayBuffer[DisplayObject]
    traverse(root, flat)
    flat
  }
}
```

This is fine, however, when I'm calling this function, I'm loosing a lot of type information:

```
val root = new DisplayObject with Position with Composite
root.children += new DisplayObject with Composable with Position
val list = flatten(root)
```

The type of `list` is now `List[DisplayObject]`. I'm losing the Position information. So I thought about adding generics into the mix : 
(**update**: added body)

```
  def genericFlatten[T](root:T with Composite) : ArrayBuffer[T] =
  {
    def traverse(composite:T with Composite, acc:ArrayBuffer[T])
    {
      acc += composite
      for(composable <- composite.children)
      {
        composable match {
          case com:T with Composite => traverse(com, acc)
          case composable:T with Composable => acc += composable
        }
      }
    }

    val flat = new ArrayBuffer[T]
    traverse(root, flat)
    flat
  }
```

However, calling this gives me this weird result : the type of the returned list is now `List[DisplayObject with Position with Composite]`, which is wrong, because some children of the tree (the leafs) will not have the Composite trait. I was expecting the type T to be infered to `DisplayObject with Position`. No?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the body of `flatten`.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but I feel a certain misconception of what the type inferer does: if you do not specify the type, the type inferer will try to figure it out, but it won't replace the type you have defined yourself.

Let's take your first shot:

```
def flatten(root:DisplayObject with Composite) : List[DisplayObject]
```

Here you set up the return type. This method will always return a `List[DisplayObject]` and there is absolutely nothing to infer. The signature is perfectly complete.

Let's take your second shot:

```
def flatten[T](root:T with Composite) : List[T]
```

Here again, no type inference. There are generics parameters, and the generic value will be checked by the compiler . You can write this method in Java, which has no type inference at all

---

If I have correctly interpreted your answer, you would like to flatten the elements in the `children` list without losing their type. Hower, if we look to the Composite trait:

```
trait Composite extends Composable { 
        val children:ArrayBuffer[Composable] = new ArrayBuffer[Composable] 
}
```

Here we have a `val children` that has type `ArrayBuffer[Composable]`, more specifically it has type `ArrayBuffer[T]` with generic parameter `T = Composable` . This is the compile type you enforce in declaration and in a static typed programming language such as Scala or Java this is not allowed to change during the execution of your program.

This the key point for understanding your problem: try to think about it in Java. If you have a `List<Object>` you can put inside an Integer, but that won't turn your `List<Object>` into a `List<Integer>`. Let's break your code for adding a children into two rows.

```
val firstChildren:DisplayObject with Position = new DisplayObject with Position
root.children += firstChildren
```

Here, as soon as your `firstChildren` val gets out of scope, you will lose its type information. If you access it through the root.children you won't know it's a `DisplayObject with Position` but only a `Composable`. Furthermore firstChildren is a DisplayObject with

---

**Disclaimer:**

**What you are trying to is not trivial however because Composable and Composite classes have a circular reference. I have been breaking it to provide some simple working code, but I have to warn you it would take you a certain amount of experience in Scala before you could master the type system well. **

You need somehow to keep the information about the children type on the parent and the information about the parent on the children. You therefore need two type parameters.

```
  trait Composable[K,T<:Composite[K,T]] {
    val parent:T
  }

  trait Composite[K,T<:Composite[K,T]] extends Composable[K,T] {
    val children:ArrayBuffer[K] = new ArrayBuffer[K]
  }

  trait Position { val x = 0.0d; val y = 0.0d }

  class DisplayObject

  def flatten[K,T<:Composite[K,T]](root:DisplayObject with Composite[K,T]) : List[K] =
  {
    root.children.toList
  }
  class ComposableDisplayObjectWithPosition extends DisplayObject with Position with        Composite[DisplayObject with Position,ComposableDisplayObjectWithPosition]{
      // dangerous
      val parent = this
    }

  def main(args:Array[String]){

    val root = new ComposableDisplayObjectWithPosition
    root.children += new DisplayObject with Position
    val list:List[DisplayObject with Position] = flatten(root)
    println(list)
  }
```

Comment: That is indead not an easy task. The circular definition makes it difficult to built what I intent using generics.

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I am no Scala expert, the argument below is generic (pardon thee pun).*

The signature `func(param:T with X)` means that if the actual parameter of `func` is of type `A`, then it is required that `A<:T` *and* `A<:X`. These requirements are totally separate.

There's no `without` in the type system. If `T` is generic, it is not inferred to be `A without X`, there's no such thing. `T` is inferred to be `A`, as it's the <s>only</s> easiest and most useful way to satisfy `A<:T`. `A<:X` is checked separately.

If you pass `DisplayObject with Position with Composite` to `flatten`, you get back `DisplayObject with Position with Composite`. If you pass `Foo with Bar with Composite`, you get that back too. You can't subtract `Composite`, since there's no such thing as `without`. I don't know why anyone would want to. I cannot imagine a situation where extra type information would hurt.

Comment: It hurts currently because the extra type information is wrong. I get a `List[DisplayObject with Composite with Position]`, which might contains objects that are not Composite.

Comment: The type inference engine doesn't lie (unless it has a bug). It returns `List[... with Composite]` because that's what you can actually have with a *recursive* `flatten` function. If you want it to typecheck, your objects must be `with Composite` *at all levels*.

Comment: Please disregard the previous comment, it looks like I don't fully understand how `genericFlatten` works.

Comment: OK I now see that the type inference engine does in fact lie in this case. I forgot about '-unchecked'. `genericFlatten` does not actually typecheck, but the compiler lets you get away with it, and you get a `ClassCastException` at run time.

Comment: To make it even more apparent, you can check that it's possible to `root.children += new DisplayObject with Composable` (no position). Indeed, children of `Composite` are only required to be `Composable`. They don't inherit the `Position` trait from their (run-time) parent! You will get an array of `DisplayObject` (only) that *thinks* it's an array of `DisplayObject with Position`.